# why to specify default value to primarykey field in Django models

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

If we specify a field as `primary_key` then why it is again asking to specify default value for the same field. Following is my model structure.

```
class ScatterxBloggerProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255L, primary_key=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255L, null=False)
    profileimage = models.TextField(max_length=1000L, null=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=255L, null=False)
    since = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    writesabout = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    fbhandle = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True, null=False)
    twthandle = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True, null=False)
    lkdhandle = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True, null=False)
    distributionavailable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I had created this table earlier with few fields absent and having django default id as `primary_key`. Now I am adding a new primary key. When I try to do migration, it asks me:

`? The field 'ScatterxBloggerProfile.username' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ? Please select a choice:`

Why would I specify a default value?

Comment: Don't use a username as the primary key, use the one created by the DB.

Comment: You'll lose a good bit of functionality built into Django, queries like this for example `Model.object.filter(pk__gt=some_num)`. There's really no reason not to. Your username field can be unique without being the primary key.

Comment: Agreed ! But, I want to sort the bloggers alphabetically and use the username key everywhere and provide functionalities for users to just input username and get everything! Plus, even if I don't make it `primary_key` as keep as just unique, then also it asks the same thing!

Comment: You can do all of those things without making the primary key a username. Unless you understand your database system very deeply just let it handle the primary key assignment.

Comment: Fine! And one more thing, for fields like fbhandle, twthandle etc what is the need to specify a default value as its asking for their default value as well while migrating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96858/discussion-between-ianauld-and-namita-maharanwar).